# MS SQL index rebuild fixes timeouts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

we have an MS SQL query, which is rather complex in terms of joins. It's purpose is to search for specific type of entities. We recently spent some time optimizing it and setting the right indexes.

Though at some points in time (have not noticed any rules, so seems arbitrary) the web application starts timing out when utilizing this query. We then can go into the DB and rebuild the indexes on 2 tables included in the SQL and it gets back to normal... That happens occasionally.

Now pardon my ignorance, should the MSSQL rebuild the indexes itself at the optimum moments of time?
Otherwise, would we need to schedule for the index maintenance to run once we hit some level of fragmentation?
Please feel free to ignore my questions and guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe table statistics go off? It can be happen, when indexed fields have 'skewed' values distribution - like 50% records have same value and other 50% are all different - and adding records doesn't follow same kind of pattern. Rebuilding index recreates statistics - but easier way would be 'update statistics mytable with fullscan'. SQL server itself updates tables statistics automatically (if not disabled), but it doesn't use all records for sampling; this 'fullscan' hint forces to sample all data.

Comment: The next time problem happens I will try to just run the `UPDATE STATISTICS mytable` instead. Or is there any other way to analyze if table stats go off, i.e. logs?

Comment: Check out the excellent index maintenance article by [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

Comment: "should the MSSQL rebuild the indexes itself at the optimum moments of time? " - It doesn't. It auto updates statistics based on a heuristic threshold. You need to implement a maintenance schedule (Standard DBA bread'n'butter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Production systems should have regular statistics maintenance and possibly some less frequent index maintenance.

Since SQL Server does not (currently) do this for you out of the box, implement [Ola Hallegren's Index and Statistics Maintenance scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/). DBA's use these.

I used to rebuild indexes weekly, but now prefer to update statistics nightly, and perform less frequent index rebuilds.

<strike>I implement a weekly rebuild of all fragmented indexes (> 50%) and a nightly job (where required) to maintain heavily used (and heavily inserted into) tables.all fragmented indexes (> 50%) and a nightly job (where required) to maintain heavily used (and heavily inserted into) tables.</strike>